# Enable/disable JS function on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two JS snippets and would like to implement this logic: second JS is running **until** first one activates (it activates on click and I also have menu that opens when pressed on this button) and then when clicked again (menu closes) the second JS snippet must be unpaused (and all over again). 
Please suggest how can I 'merge' them together?

1)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#menuicon-label').click(function(e) {
    var clicks = jQuery(this).data('clicks');
    if (clicks) {
      jQuery('html').css({'position': '', 'left': '', 'right': '', 'top': '', 'bottom': '', 'overflow': ''});
    } else {
      jQuery('html').css({'position': 'fixed', 'left': '0', 'right': '0', 'top': '0', 'bottom': '0', 'overflow': 'hidden'});
    }
    jQuery(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
  });
});
</script>
```

2)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
     jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
         var top = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

         if(top>48) { // height of float header
             jQuery('#main').css("paddingTop", "96px");
             jQuery('#cloakaglobal').css("display", "none");
         } else {
             jQuery('#main').css("paddingTop", "0px");
             jQuery('#cloakaglobal').css("display", "");
         }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of unbind feature in jQuery. Make the below changes in the first snippet -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
  var trackTheSecondJs=true;
  jQuery('#menuicon-label').click(function(e) {
    if(trackTheSecondJs){
       jQuery(window).unbind("scroll",scrollHandler);
       trackTheSecondJs=false;
    }else{
       jQuery(window).bind("scroll",scrollHandler);
       trackTheSecondJs=true;
    }
    var clicks = jQuery(this).data('clicks');
    if (clicks) {
      jQuery('html').css({'position': '', 'left': '', 'right': '', 'top': '', 'bottom': '', 'overflow': ''});
    } else {
      jQuery('html').css({'position': 'fixed', 'left': '0', 'right': '0', 'top': '0', 'bottom': '0', 'overflow': 'hidden'});
    }
    jQuery(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
  });
});
</script>
```

Now in the second snippet, have the pointer to the function instead of giving the function itself as parameter to scroll function. So that using this pointer, unbind can be done in the first snippet as we did above.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function scrollHandler(){
         var top = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

         if(top>48) { // height of float header
             jQuery('#main').css("paddingTop", "96px");
             jQuery('#cloakaglobal').css("display", "none");
         } else {
             jQuery('#main').css("paddingTop", "0px");
             jQuery('#cloakaglobal').css("display", "");
         }
}
jQuery(function() {
     jQuery(window).scroll(scrollHandler);
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Sai. Solved the problem.